# How can I fill a rect with an alpha color using CoreGraphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawrect, core-graphics

In my drawRect method, I am drawing a PNG image. On top of that, I want to draw a rect with a 20% alpha color, like this:

```
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2] set];
UIRectFill(rect);
```

The problem is, that the alpha property seems to get ignored. No alpha is applied at all, just a black rectangle is drawn. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CGContextSetBlendMode()` before you draw the rect.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thanks.

I used a similar function:

  UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(rect, kCGBlendModeNormal);

Answer (score 0):

Set your view background color to transparent… It should work.